# The coditions for the function form of Green's function in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, lorentz-symmetry, greens-functions

I've started studying QFT a couple of months ago and I'm reading a text book written by T. Kugo. In the chapter about gauge field theory( the same content is in T. Kugo and I. Ojima(1978)), I found incomprehensible statement:

Firstly, the Lagrangean of their theory is
 $$L = \frac{1}{4}F^{a\mu\nu}F^{a}_{\mu\nu} + L_{matter} - \partial_{\mu} B^{a}\cdot A^{\mu} + \frac{\alpha}{2}B^aB^a - i\partial_{\mu}\overline{c}^a\cdot D^{\mu}c^a$$
where $c^{a},\overline{c}^{a}$are ghost fields and $B^{a}$ is a Nakanishi-Lautrup field.This is Lorentz and $L_{matter}$ is gauge invariant.(Gauge group is assumed to be semisimple)

Let the two point Green's function in momentum space$$\int \mathrm{d}x e^{-ip(x-y)}<0|TA_{\mu}^{a}(x)B_{\nu}^{b}(y)|0> \equiv f_{\mu}^{ab}(p) $$( this is a notation I introduced here just for simplicity. )

It seems to me that he derives $f_{\mu}^{ab}(p)=-\delta^{ab}p_{\mu}/p^2$ only from $p^{\mu}f_{\mu}^{ab}(p)=-\delta^{ab}$ because  we know $f_{\mu}^{ab}(p)$is proportional to  $p_{\mu}$ from symmetry . I don't get explanation for this.(or maybe this is wrong.)

this may be very trivial fact but I can't understand it. Can we put such a strong condition only from Lorentz invariance?

Comment: p and f are inverse of each other. in the path integral approach we have to find the inverse of differential operator.that differential operator which act on some function gives delta function that function is Green function.here your differential operator is p.that can be seen from lagrangian(coupling between A and B).so you have just inverse them normalize them if you want.

Comment: Sorry posted wrongly.  Im afraid i need more explanation. I can understand pf = 1 and this equation has four variables. Linear algebra tells this dosent determine one solution. How p/p^2 is chosen ?

Comment: From the Lorentz invariance f should be some one index quantity multiplied by some constant(f=A c).so upon substitution of f in inverse relation you will get p A c==I where A is some vector and c is just constant.so from comparision you will get the required f.

Comment: How Lorentz invariance restrict f proportional to p is the very point i've been wondering. But your answer helped me make it clear. Every function with Lorentz index is written as a linear combination of tensorial functions of p and invariant tesors. And in current case f can be written as f = c(p^2)･p and pf = 1 determines c. This is trivial but i couldn't understand it intuitively. Thanks a lot.